# numpy row/column to 1D vector?

Tags: python, numpy

I have row/column vectors:

```
row = np.r_['r', [1, 2]]
col = np.r_['c', [1, 2]]
```

and I want to convert them to 1D arrays, equivalent to

```
np.array([1, 2])
```

I tried `ravel, flatten, squeeze`, but they all return the original array (a 2D array).

My question is

- why don't they work?
- what is the appropriate way of doing it?

Comment: This parameter for `r_` is rarely used; I had to look at the docs to verify what the answers were saying.  The usual warnings about `np.matrix` being discouraged apply.  So does the `.A1` property:  `row.A1`, `col.A1`.

Comment: @hpaulj: I've seen it often in examples in the docs of numpy/pandas etc themselves. Never saw `.A1` before though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have matrices and not arrays, that's why in doesn't work.

Create a view on the matrix and reshape it:

```
np.asarray(row).reshape(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case `np.r_` is creating a matrix

```
row = np.r_['r', [1, 2]]
col = np.r_['c', [1, 2]]

print(type(row))
# numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix
```

You can flatten them by first converting them to an array

```
print(np.array(row).flatten().shape)
# (2,)
```